# Elasticsearch multiple analysers not working

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a small test regs with a title like :
'**Santos (SAN) X Avaí FC (AVAI) - Canindé (São Paulo-SP)**'

If I try to search any word like '**san**' or '**avai**' or '**avaí**' or '**santos**' it works fine. But if I try to search for '**Santos (SAN) X Avaí FC (AVAI)**', it should return just 1 reg and it returns all 3 regs.

Here is the test data:
https://gist.github.com/PtkFerraro/83c4b693cf770c3320fe0530a4e1ddc7

Here is the analysers & mapping
https://gist.github.com/PtkFerraro/eb3244bf8c589b234a13d7f2b693cf77

Here is the search:
https://gist.github.com/PtkFerraro/c0f8ed300566cce3b5118fff1522a421

thanks in advance

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "title_default_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "title_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["lowercase","brazilian_filter","asciifolding"
                    ]
                },
                "title_snowball_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "title_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["lowercase","brazilian_filter","asciifolding","snowball"
                    ]
                },
                "title_shingle_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "title_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["lowercase","brazilian_filter","shingle","asciifolding"
                    ]
                },
                "title_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "title_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["lowercase","brazilian_filter","asciifolding","edge_ngram_filter"
                    ]
                },
                "title_search_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "title_tokenizer",
                    "filter": ["lowercase","brazilian_filter","asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "brazilian_filter": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "name": "brazilian",
                    "token_chars": ["letter", "digit"]
                },
                "edge_ngram_filter": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 50,
                    "token_chars": ["letter", "digit"]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "title_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "letter"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "entersport": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "properties": {
                "is_adult": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "match_start": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "match_title": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "title": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "title_default_analyzer"
                        },
                        "snowball": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "title_snowball_analyzer"
                        },
                        "shingles": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "title_shingle_analyzer"
                        },
                        "ngrams": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "title_ngram_analyzer",
                            "search_analyzer": "title_search_analyzer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html)

Comment: @femtoRgon but if someone just type one word ? I would have to have 2 search (1 for phrase and another for words)?

Comment: which ES version are you running?

Comment: @Phil Elastic 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to support two different kinds of searches: (1) where you match a single term like `san` or `avai` to the football match title and (2) where exact phrase matches part or all of the match title.

The [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) that you are using is parsed into individual terms so in your example `Santos (SAN) X Avaí FC (AVAI)` contains the `X` token which match all 3 sample documents because they each contain `X`.

Your query:

```
{
    "query_string": {
        "query": "Santos (SAN) X Avaí FC (AVAI)",
        "fields": [
            "title^10",
            "match_title.snowball^2",
            "match_title.shingles^2",
            "match_title.ngrams"
        ]
    }
}
```

If you want to match the entire phrase you need to use a query that will do that. [Match phrase queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) were suggested in the comments. You can also use a match query with the `operator` set to `and` the terms in the query. This would allow you to use the same query type to match `avai` as `Santos (SAN) X Avaí FC (AVAI)`.

I think you might be happier with something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":      "Santos (SAN) X Avaí FC (AVAI)",
      "fields":     [
            "title^10",
            "match_title.snowball^2",
            "match_title.shingles^2",
            "match_title.ngrams"
        ],
        "operator":   "and" 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Phil..thanks for the AND. Worked fine!. Just made a little change in your answer to use multi_match because de way it was was not working. But now I came with another question... querystring x multi_match. For this case, what is the better? cheers

Comment: I tend to stay away from query string queries in general just because it isn't as clear as what you are actually searching because it uses its own "query language". For you, I'm not sure I know enough to say which is "better". I'd recommend multimatches and/or match queries unless it doesn't work for you.